# An example of parallel execution of Behat / Drupal scenarios based on outlines?

Tags: php, drupal, selenium-webdriver, behat

We have a set of front end UI tests implemented in PHP Behat extending DrupalContext.  All scenarios are driven using Scenario Outlines.  I am investigating how to run these in parallel against a WebDriver grid.  Ideally, I'd like to run each permutation of each scenario outline in parallel, but would be happy to just be able to run the features in parallel.

How to run test parallel on Behat 3?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0):

try to use parallel GNU to run features in parallel

http://zalas.eu/running-behat-in-parallel-with-selenium-grid/